# Define database connection for supervisor

Tags: laravel, supervisord

In my laravel 8 app, I have three database connections, viz `Database-0`, `Database-1`, `Database-2`.

`Database-0` used for authenticating users so it has `users` table and Laravel `Auth` method retrieve user using this connection as I have set it in `passport` configuration file.
`Database-1` and `Database-2` connection used for all other purposes except authentication.

In my `users` table I have just two users with email `first_user@example.com` and `second_user@example.com`

When user is logged in with `first_user@example.com` then `Database-1` should be used and if user is logged in with `second_user@example.com` then `Database-2` should be used.

To acheive this I have created a middleware and register it in `$middleware` group so it run for all the request. In this middleware, I am checking the logged in user email and based on that I am setting database connection.

Up until now everything works perfectly

Now I have a job of that is being queued and I am using `database` as my QUEUE_CONNECTION. so my job stored in database `jobs` table. I have configured supervisor for processing this job.

Now the problem is when supervisor make query to retrieve job, my middleware doesn't get called and it throws following error

`invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: select * from` jobs `where ....)`

So my question is how can I set database connection for supervisor to choose from database when retrieving jobs?

**middleware**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $auth_email = Auth::guard('api')->user()?->email;
    if ($auth_email === 'first_user@example.com') {
        config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-1']);
    } elseif ($auth_email === 'second_user@example.com') {
        config(['database.connections.fe_mysql.database' => 'Database-2']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**supervisor config**

```
[program:queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/laravel-project/artisan queue:work --queue=admin
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs=7200
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel-project/worker.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the config() function to set extra or overwrite existing connection settings.

```
config(['database.connections.mynewconnection' => {settings here}]);
```

Keep in mind that these settings are cached. So when you need to use the new settings, purge the DB cache for the connection you're gonna use.

```
DB::purge('mynewconnection');
```

You can also manipulate the default connection that is used. This can come in handy if you wish to use migrations over different connections and keep track of them with a migration table within the used connection. Or other cool stuff ofcourse...

```
DB::setDefaultConnection('mynewconnection');
```

Comment: I have already created the middleware for setting up the dataabse connection. the problem is the middleware doesn't get called when `supervisor` retrive the jobs